# How exactly should unit tests be written without mocking extensively?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, integration-tests, mocking, stub

As I understand, the point of unit tests is to test *units of code in isolation*. This means, that:

1. They should not break by **any unrelated code** change elsewhere in the codebase.
2. Only one unit test should break by a bug in the tested unit, as opposed to integration tests (which may break in heaps).

All of this implies, that every outside dependency of a tested unit, should be mocked out. And I mean **all the outside dependencies**, not only the "outside layers" such as networking, filesystem, database, etc..

This leads to a logical conclusion, that *virtually every unit test needs to mock*. On the other hand, a quick Google search about mocking reveals tons of articles that claim that "mocking is a code smell" and should mostly (though not completely) be avoided.

Now, to the question(s).

1. How should unit tests be written properly?
2. Where exactly does the line between them and the integration tests lie?

---

**Update 1**

Please consider the following pseudo code:

```
class Person {
    constructor(calculator) {}

    calculate(a, b) {
        const sum = this.calculator.add(a, b);

        // do some other stuff with the `sum`
    }
}
```

Can a test that tests the `Person.calculate` method without mocking the `Calculator` dependency (given, that the `Calculator` is a lightweight class that does not access "the outside world") be considered a unit test?

Comment: Part of this is just design experience that will come with time. You'll learn how to structure your components so that they do not have many difficult to mock dependencies. This means that testability must be a secondary design goal of any software. This goal is much easier to satisfy if test are written before or together with the code, e.g. using TDD and/or BDD.

Comment: I understand that, however I fail to see a clear line defined between a unit and an integration test. When does the one starts becoming the other?

Comment: There is no clear line between them at least in part because there are so many different opinions on what constitutes a unit test and what doesn't.

Comment: Then based on what metrics should they be divided into separate folders, as everyone suggests they should?

Comment: Put tests that run quickly and reliably into one folder. Put tests that are slow and potentially fragile into another. Run the tests in the first folder as often as possible (literally every time you pause in typing and the code compiles is the ideal, but not all dev environments support this). Run the slower tests less often (when you have a coffee break for example). Don't worry about unit and integration names. Call them fast and slow if you want. It doesn't matter.

Comment: Might not be the answer you're looking for, but why not split the `calculate` method further? `doSomeOtherStuff(sum) { [...] }`, which you then can test *without* depending on `calculator`? -- Usually, there are two "kinds" of methods. The ones that actually do something, and the ones that call other methods and probably shove results from one into the other. Unit Tests (at least imho) should primarily focus on the first kind (assuming the second kind doesn't have an overly complicated flow).

Comment: "that virtually every unit test needs to mock" **Yeah, so?** "a quick Google search about mocking reveals tons of articles that claim that "mocking is a code smell"" **they're wrong**.

Comment: There's two views here "test in isolation" where mocking is used extensively and the code itself is tested, but without the safety net of ensuring it works in context, this often runs more quickly and some people say it leads to better structured code. The other "test in context" where we pass exactly the kinds of related objects it will encounter in a production environment. This is a better safety net for changes in the code, but can lead to complex and fragile test frameworks. People will (as you've seen- argue passionately for either, but in practise, usually fall somewhere between.

Comment: @Michael Simply stating 'yeah, so' and declaring the opposing view wrong isn't a great way to approach a contentious subject like this. Perhaps write an answer and elaborate on why you think mocking should be everywhere, and perhaps why you think 'tons of articles' are inherently wrong?

Comment: Since you didn't give a citation for "mocking is a code smell", I can only guess that you're misinterpreting what you read. Mocking is not a code smell. The need to use reflection or other shenanigans to inject your mocks is a code smell. The difficulty of mocking is inversely proportional to the quality of your API design. If you can write simple straightforward unit tests that just pass mocks to constructors, you're doing it right.

Comment: FWIW, I've never heard that mocking is a code smell. IMO, it's just a tool to use. I think one thing to keep in mind, design preferences might vary a lot from team to team, you should evaluate "code smells" on their merit if it's up to you (as a designer) to choose what is and isn't a code smell . Also, with the exception of some common sense things you probably know already (e.g., don't name your variables in Klingon or make a whole file with no whitespace at all), advice consisting of "X is a code smell" without any context, justification, or use cases may not help your project.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning here that "mocking" is an overloaded and potentially ambiguous word. [Mocks Aren't Stubs](https://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html), but some people use the word "mock" to refer to any kind of test double, while others reserve it for special-purpose interaction-validating mechanisms. Using test doubles is a natural part of testing, and I'm not aware of anyone saying that test doubles are always a code smell. Using a mocking framework to validate interactions is different -- it is controversial and polarizing at best.

Comment: Have you try to check "clean arhitecture" ?

Comment: Mocks and spies specifically allow you to perform white-box testing (over stubs and other doubles). That in of itself, and white-box testing in general, is not a code smell. However - being literally unable to perform any kind of automated black-box testing of your code api and having your entire test rig dependant on your actual implementation *is* a code smell. Tests should be decoupled from implementation as much as any other piece of code. Regularly having the majority of your "unit tests" just check that dependant function x ran y times with input z screams both fragile code *and* tests.

Comment: Re. integration tests - I don't think the distinction between a unit test and integration test as an integration test testing "clusters of code" is useful. I prefer to reserve the term "integration test" for testing components that integrate with other systems. E.g. an integration test for an HTTP client should actually call an HTTP endpoint. Tests for "clusters of [my] code" are still unit tests, because all unit tests test clusters of code, unless you are going to start stubbing out things like lists and strings.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

> the point of unit tests is to test units of code in isolation.

Martin Fowler on [Unit Test](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/UnitTest.html)

> Unit testing is often talked about in software development, and is a term that I've been familiar with during my whole time writing programs. Like most software development terminology, however, it's very ill-defined, and I see confusion can often occur when people think that it's more tightly defined than it actually is.

What Kent Beck wrote in *Test Driven Development, By Example*

> I call them "unit tests", but they don't match the accepted definition of unit tests very well

Any given claim of "the point of unit tests is" will depend heavily on what definition of "unit test" is being considered.

If your perspective is that your program is composed of many small units that depend on one another, and if you constrain yourself to a style that tests each unit in isolation, then a lot of [test doubles](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestDouble.html) is an inevitable conclusion.

The conflicting advice that you see comes from people operating under a different set of assumptions.

For example, if you are writing tests to support developers during the process of refactoring, and *splitting one unit into two* is a refactoring that should be supported, then something needs to give.  Maybe this kind of test needs a different name (ex: "component test" was used by Boris Beizer)?  Or maybe we need a different understanding of "unit".

You may want to compare:

- Ian Cooper's [TDD: Where Did It All Go Wrong](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EZ05e7EMOLM)
- JBRainsberger's [Integrated Tests are a Scam](https://vimeo.com/80533536)

> Can a test that tests the Person.calculate method without mocking the Calculator dependency (given, that the Calculator is a lightweight class that does not access "the outside world") be considered a unit test?

I think that's the wrong question to ask; it's again an argument about *labels*, when I believe what we actually care about are *properties*.

When I'm introducing changes to the code, I don't care about isolation of tests -- I already know that "the mistake" is somewhere in my current stack of unverified edits.  If I run the tests frequently, then I limit the depth of that stack, and finding the mistake is trivial (in the extreme case, the tests are run after every edit -- the max depth of the stack is one).  But running the tests isn't the goal -- it's an interruption -- so there is value in reducing the impact of the interruption.  One way of reducing the interruption is to ensure that the tests are fast ([Gary Bernhardt suggests 300ms](https://web.archive.org/web/20140505212321/https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/blog/2014/tdd-straw-men-and-rhetoric), but I haven't figured out how to do that in my circumstances).

If invoking `Calculator::add` doesn't significantly increase the time required to run the test (or any of the other important properties for this use case), then I wouldn't bother using a test double -- it doesn't provide benefits that outweigh the costs.

Notice the two assumptions here: a human being as part of the cost evaluation, and the short stack of unverified changes in the benefit evaluation.  In circumstances where those conditions do not hold, the value of "isolation" changes quite a bit.

See also [Hot Lava](https://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/book/chapter_hot_lava.html), by Harry Percival.

Comment: one thing that mocking add does do is prove that calculator *can* be mocked i.e. that the design does not couple person and calculator (though this can also be checked in other ways)

Comment: This video was an eye openor

Comment: This answer is gold. I'm looking into "Chicago\Detroit vs London schools of TDD" and from what I can tell in the internet, the London school (mockists) win the PR (public relations). They're louder. But that's also a reason unit tests are considered hard and fragile and not worth the cost. TDD tests are better in that regard.

Comment: That's interesting - based on my reading, the voices of the London school _lost_ the PR battle.

Answer (score 66):

> How exactly should unit tests be written without mocking extensively?

By minimising side-effects in your code.

Taking your example code, if `calculator` for example talks to a web API, then either you create fragile tests that rely on being able to interact with that web API, or you create a mock of it. If however its a deterministic, state-free set of calculation functions, then you don't (and shouldn't) mock it. If you do, you risk your mock behaving differently to the real code, leading to bugs in your tests.

Mocks should only be needed for code that read/writes to the file system, databases, URL endpoints etc; that are dependent on the environment you are running under; or that are highly stateful and non-deterministic in nature. So if you keep those parts of the code to a minimum and hide them behind abstractions, then they are easy to mock and the rest of your code avoids the need for mocks.

For the code points that do have side effects, it's worth writing tests that mock and tests that don't. The latter though need care as they will inherently be fragile and possibly slow. So you may want to only run them say overnight on a CI server, rather than every time you save and build your code. The former tests though should be run as often as practicable.
As to whether each test is then a unit or integration test becomes academic and avoids "flame wars" over what is and isn't a unit test.

Comment: This is the correct answer both in practice and in terms of dodging a meaningless semantic debate.

Comment: Do you have an example of a non-trivial open source codebase that uses such a style and still gets good test coverage?

Comment: @JoeriSebrechts every single FP one? [Example](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/tree/master/test)

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for, as that's just a collection of functions that are independent of each other, not a system of functions that call each other. How do you get around having to construct complex arguments to a function for the purpose of testing it, if that function is one of the top-level ones? E.g. the core loop of a game.

Comment: @JoeriSebrechts hmm, either I'm misunderstanding what you want, or you didn't dig deep enough into the example I gave. The ramda functions use internal calls all over the place in their source (e.g. `R.equals`). Because these are for the most part pure functions, they generally aren't mocked out in the tests.

Comment: « If you do, you risk your mock behaving differently to the real code, leading to bugs in your tests » but doesn’t the exact same problem applies when mocking external APIs ? And since the resolution to this problem is then to make an integration test, why not mock everything ? I’m 100% thinking the way this answer does, but I still wonder, is that just because of the waste of time ? I also think code tested with mocks is harder to refactor.

Comment: @SteveChamaillard use integration tests to test components that integrate, isolate logical units from those by making them take data, not dependencies, and test those. Glue them together with orchestrators that call the impure components and pass the result to the pure components. Test the orchestrators only at a high level with simple end-to-end tests (which may use fake external dependencies or not). This way the vast majority of your unit tests are mock-free in anything but the most trivial of applications.

Answer (score 35):

These questions are quite different in their difficulty. Let's take question 2 first.

Unit tests and integration tests are clearly separated. A unit test tests *one* unit (method or class) and uses other units only as much as necessary to achieve that goal. Mocking may be necessary, but it is not the point of the test. An integration test tests the interaction between different *actual* units. This difference is the entire reason why we *need* both unit and integration testing - if one did the job of the other well enough, we wouldn't, but it's turned out that it's usually more efficient to use two specialized tools rather than one generalized tool.

Now for the important question: How should you unit test? As said above, unit tests should construct auxiliary structures *only as far as necessary*. Often it is easier to use a mock database than your real database or even *any* real database. However, mocking in itself has no value. If often happens that it is in fact easier to use *actual* components of another layer as input for a mid-level unit test. If so, don't hesitate to use them.

Many practitioners are afraid that if unit test B reuses classes that were already tested by unit test A, then a defect in unit A causes test failures in multiple places. I consider this not a problem: a test suite has to succeed *100%* in order to give you the reassurance you need, so it is not a big problem to have too many failures - after all, you *do* have a defect. The only critical problem would be if a defect triggered too *few* failures.

Therefore, don't make a religion of mocking. It is a means, not an end, so if you can get away with avoiding the extra effort, you should do so.

Comment: `The only critical problem would be if a defect triggered too few failures.` this is one of the weak points of mocking. We have to "programme" the expected behaviour so, we might fail at doing so, causing our tests to end as "false positives". But mocking is a very useful technique in order to achieve determinism (the most important condition of testing). I use them in all my projects when possible. They also show me when the integration is too complex or the dependency too tight.

Comment: If a unit that's being tested uses other units, isn't it really an integration test? Because in essence this unit would be testing the interaction between the said units, exactly like an integration test would.

Comment: @AlexanderLomia not necessarily. If you consider these units to be "implementation details" of the unit under test. It depends on what do you call "unit". Unit in this context is not necessarily a synonym of "single" or "only one".

Comment: @AlexanderLomia: What would you call a unit? Would you call 'String' a unit as well? I would, but I wouldn't dream of mocking it.

Comment: "*Unit tests and integration tests are clearly separated. A unit test tests one unit (method or class) and uses other units only as much as necessary to achieve that goal*". Here's the rub. That's *your* definition of a unit test. Mine is quite different. So the distinction between them is only "clearly separated" for any given definition but the separation varies between definitions.

Comment: For me there are just two things needed for something to be a unit: (1) it's fast in execution, (2) it executes in isolation. If my app reads a file, processes it and then writes a new one, that entire "processes it" is a unit if it meets the above two criteria.

Comment: " a test suite has to succeed 100% in order to give you the reassurance you need, so it is not a big problem to have too many failures - after all, you do have a defect". If you ever worked on a large code base with tens of thousands or more tests, you will see why this is just not true: If a single failure in a core component (or much worse some infrastructure change that influences the core component - say a update) causes hundreds of tests to fail, you'll have a very hard time finding the original problem.

Comment: @Voo Having worked with such codebases, whilst it can be a nuisance to find the original problem (especially if the architecture has painted over the things you'd use to debug it), I've still had more trouble from mocks that caused the tests to keep working after the code they were used to test had broken.

Comment: @james_pic That's why you have integration tests (or whatever you want to call them) that don't mock those things away. But absolutely there's a trade-off and I'm not saying I know where the sweet spot is. At the same time I do think that there is a problem when 2000 tests fail because a .NET framework update introduced a problem in some core functionality (*cough* not that this were ever based on a somewhat recent problem here at work).

Comment: @DavidArno Your definitions of unit vs integration tests are your opinions, but Kilian's explanations do match the definitions of the ISTQB, a widely recognized testing qualification organization (see section 2.2. in their [foundation level syllabus 2018](https://www.istqb.org/downloads/syllabi/foundation-level-syllabus.html)), and also the definitions in [ISO 24765:2017 “Systems and software engineering – Vocabulary”](https://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/c071952_ISO_IEC_IEEE_24765_2017.zip).

Comment: *However, mocking in itself has no value.* - This.  So much this.  It is crucial to recognize that *mocks are made of code*.  They can have bugs.  They require maintenance.  Like anything else in programming, you shouldn't create them unless the benefits outweigh the costs.

Answer (score 10):

Mocking should only be used as a last resort, even in unit tests.

A method is not a unit, and even a class is not a unit. A unit is any logical separation of code that makes sense, regardless of what you call it. An important element of having well tested code is being able to freely refactor, and part of being able to freely refactor means that you don't have to change your tests in order to do so. The more you mock, the more you have to change your tests when you refactor. If you consider the method the unit, then you have to change your tests every time you refactor. And if you consider the class the unit, then you have to change your tests every time you want to break a class up into multiple classes. When you have to refactor your tests in order to refactor your code, it makes people choose to not refactor their code, which is just about the worst thing that can happen to a project. It is essential that you can break a class up into multiple classes without having to refactor your tests, or you're going to end up with oversized 500 line spaghetti classes. If you are treating methods or classes as your units with unit testing, you are probably not doing Object Oriented Programming but some sort of mutant functional programming with objects.

Isolating your code for a unit test doesn't mean that you mock everything outside of it. If it did, you'd have to mock your language's Math class, and absolutely no one thinks that's a good idea. Internal dependencies should not be treated any differently than external dependencies. You trust that they are well tested and work like they are supposed to. The only real difference is that if your internal dependencies are breaking your modules, you can stop what you're doing to fix it rather than having to go post an issue on GitHub and either dig into a codebase you don't understand to fix it or hope for the best.

Isolating your code just means that you treat your internal dependencies like black boxes and don't test things that are happening inside them. If you have Module B which accepts inputs of 1, 2, or 3, and you have Module A, which calls it, you don't have your tests for Module A do each of those options, you just pick one and use that. It means that your tests for Module A should test the different ways you treat the responses from Module B, not the things that you pass into it.

So, if your controller passes in a complex object to a dependency, and that dependency does several possible things, maybe saving it to the database and maybe returning a variety of errors, but all your controller actually does is simply check to see if it returns an error or not and pass that information along, then all you test in your controller is one test for if it returns an error and passes it along and one test for if it does not return an error. You don't test whether something got saved in the database or what kind of error the error is, because that would be an integration test. You do not have to mock the dependency in order to do this. You have isolated the code.

Answer (score 9):

OK, so to answer your questions directly:

> How should unit tests be written properly?

As you say, you should be mocking dependencies and testing just the unit in question.

> Where exactly does the line between them and integration tests lie?

An Integration test is a unit test where your dependencies are not mocked.

> Can a test that tests the Person.calculate method without mocking the
>   Calculator be considered a unit test?

No. You need to inject the calculator dependency into this code and you have a choice between a mocked version or a real one. If you use a mocked one its a unit test, if you use a real one its an integration test.

However, a caveat. do you really care what people think your tests should be called?

But your real question seems to be this:

> a quick Google search about mocking reveals tons of articles that
>   claim that "mocking is a code smell" and should mostly (though not
>   completely) be avoided.

I think the problem here is that a lot of people use mocks to completely recreate the dependencies. For example I might mock the calculator in your example as

```
public class MockCalc : ICalculator
{
     public Add(int a, int b) { return 4; }
}
```

I would not do something like:

```
myMock = Mock<ICalculator>().Add((a,b) => {return a + b;})
myPerson.Calculate()
Assert.WasCalled(myMock.Add());
```

I would argue that, that would be "testing my mock" or "testing the implementation". I would say "**Don't write Mocks!** *like that".

Other people would disagree with me, we would start massive flame wars on our blogs about the Best way to Mock, which really would make no sense unless you understood the whole background of the various approaches and really don't offer a whole lot of value to someone who just wants to write good tests.

Comment: Thanks for an exhaustive answer. As of caring about what other people think about my tests - actually I want to avoid writing semi-integration, semi-unit tests that tend to become an unreliably mess as the project progresses.

Comment: no probs, I think the problem is that the definitions of the two things aren't 100% agreed on by everyone.

Comment: I would rename your class `MockCalc` to `StubCalc`, and call it a stub not a mock. https://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html#TheDifferenceBetweenMocksAndStubs

Comment: @bdsl That article is 15 years old

Answer (score 5):

> 1. How should unit tests be implemented properly?

My rule of thumb is that proper unit tests:

- **Are coded against interfaces, not implementations**.  This has many benefits.  For one, it ensures that your classes follow the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) from [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID).  Also, this is what your other classes do (*right?*) so your tests should do the same.  Also, this allows you to test multiple implementations of the same interface while reusing much of the test code (only initialization and some assertions would change).
- **Are self-contained**.  As you said, changes in any outside code cannot affect the test result.  As such, unit tests can execute at build-time.  This means you need mocks to remove any side effects.  However, if you are following the Dependency Inversion Principle, this should be relatively easy.  Good test frameworks like [Spock](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.1/all_in_one.html) can be used to dynamically provide mock implementations of any interface to use in your tests with minimal coding.  This means that each test class only needs to exercise code from *exactly one* implementation class, plus the test framework (and maybe model classes ["beans"]).
- **Do not require a separate running application**.  If the test needs to "talk to something", whether a database or a web service, it's an integration test, not a unit test.  I draw the line at network connections or the filesystem.  A purely in-memory SQLite database, for example, is fair game in my opinion for a unit test if you really need it.

If there are utility classes from frameworks that complicate unit testing, you may even find it useful to create very simple "wrapper" interfaces and classes to facilitate mocking of those dependencies.  Those wrappers would then not necessarily be subject to unit tests.

> 2. Where exactly does the line between them [unit tests] and integration tests lie?

I have found this distinction to be the most useful:

- **Unit tests simulate "user code"**, verifying behavior of implementation classes against the desired behavior and semantics of *code-level interfaces*.
- **Integration tests simulate the user**, verifying behavior of the *running application* against specified use cases and/or formal APIs.  For a web service, the "user" would be a client application.

There is gray area here.  For example, if you can run an application in a Docker container and run the integration tests as the final stage of a build, and destroy the container afterwards, is it OK to include those tests as "unit tests"?  If this is your burning debate, you're in a pretty good place.

> 3. Is it true that virtually every unit test needs to mock?

No.  Some individual test cases will be for error conditions, like passing `null` as a parameter and verifying you get an exception.  Lots of tests like that will not require any mocks.  Also, implementations that have no side effects, for example string processing or math functions, may not require any mocks because you simply verify the output.  But most classes worth having, I think, will require at least one mock somewhere in the test code.  (The fewer, the better.)

The "code smell" issue you mentioned arises when you have a class that is overly complicated, that requires a long list of mock dependencies in order to write your tests.  This is a clue that you need to refactor the implementation and split things up, so that each class has a smaller footprint and a clearer responsibility, and is therefore more easily testable.  This will improve quality in the long run.

> Only one unit test should break by a bug in the tested unit.

I don't think this is a reasonable expectation, because it works against reuse.  You may have a `private` method, for example, that is called by multiple `public` methods published by your interface.  A bug introduced into that one method might then cause multiple test failures.  This doesn't mean you should copy the same code into each `public` method.

Answer (score 4):

> 1. They should not break by **any unrelated code** change elsewhere in the codebase.

I'm not really sure how this rule is useful. If a change in one class/method/whatever can break the behaviour of another in production code, then the things are, in reality, collaborators, and not unrelated. If your tests break and your production code doesn't, then your tests are suspect.

> 2. Only one unit test should break by a bug in the tested unit, as opposed to integration tests (which may break in heaps).

I'd regard this rule with suspicion too. If you're really good enough to structure your code and write your tests such that one bug causes exactly one unit test failure, Then you're saying you've identified all the potential bugs already, even as the codebase evolves to use cases you haven't anticipated.

> Where exactly does the line between them and integration tests lie?

I don't think that's an important distinction. What is a 'unit' of code anyhow?

Try to find entry points at which you can write tests that just 'make sense' in terms of the problem domain/business rules that *that level* of the code is dealing with. Often these tests are somewhat 'functional' in nature - put in an input, and test that the output is as expected. If the tests express a desired behaviour of the system, then they often remain quite stable even as the production code evolves and is refactored.

> How exactly should unit tests be written without mocking extensively?

Don't read too much into the word 'unit', and lean towards using your real production classes in tests, without worrying too much if you're involving more than one of them in a test. If one of them is hard to use (because it takes a lot of initialisation, or it needs to hit a real database/email server etc), then let your thoughts turn to mocking/faking.

Comment: "*What is a 'unit' of code anyhow?*" very good question that can have unexpected answers that might even depend on who is answering. Typically, most definitions of unit tests explain them as relating to a method or a class but that's not a really useful measure of a "unit" in all cases. If I have a `Person:tellStory()` method incorporates a person's details into a string then returns that, then the "story" is probably one unit. If I make a private helper method that tucks away some of the code, then I don't believe I've introduced a new unit - I don't need to test that separately.

Answer (score 2):

First, some definitions:

**A unit test tests units in isolation from other units,** but what that means is not concretely defined by any authoritative source, so let's define it a bit better: If I/O boundaries are crossed (whether that I/O is network, disk, screen, or UI input), there's a semi-objective place we can draw a line. If the code depends on I/O, it's crossing a unit boundary, and therefore it will need to mock the unit responsible for that I/O.

Under that definition, I don't see a compelling reason to mock things like pure functions, meaning that unit testing lends itself to pure functions, or functions without side-effects.

If you want to unit test units with effects, the units responsible for the effects should be mocked, but perhaps you should consider an integration test, instead. So, the short answer is: "if you need to mock, ask yourself if what you really need is an integration test." But there's a better, longer answer here, and the rabbit hole goes much deeper. Mocks may be my favorite code smell because there's so much to learn from them.

Code Smells

For this, we'll turn to Wikipedia:

> In computer programming, a code smell is any characteristic in the source code of a program that possibly indicates a deeper problem.

It continues later...

> "Smells are certain structures in the code that indicate violation of
>   fundamental design principles and negatively impact design
>   quality". Suryanarayana, Girish (November 2014). Refactoring for Software Design Smells. Morgan Kaufmann. p. 258.
>
> Code smells are usually not bugs; they are not technically incorrect and do not prevent the program from functioning.
>   Instead, they indicate weaknesses in design that may slow down
>   development or increase the risk of bugs or failures in the future.

In other words, not all code smells are bad. Instead, they are common indications that something might not be expressed in its optimal form, and the smell *may* indicate an opportunity to improve the code in question.

In the case of mocking, the smell indicates that the units which seem to be calling for mocks *depend* on the units to be mocked. It may be an indication that we haven't decomposed the problem into atomically-solvable pieces, and *that* could indicate a design flaw in the software.

The essence of all software development is the process of breaking a large problem down into smaller, independent pieces (decomposition) and composing the solutions together to form an application that solves the large problem (composition).

Mocking is required when the units used to break the large problem down into smaller parts depend on each other. Put another way, mocking is required when our supposed atomic units of composition are not really atomic, and our decomposition strategy has failed to decompose the larger problem into smaller, *independent* problems to be solved.

What makes mocking a code smell is not that there's anything inherently wrong with mocking - sometimes it is very useful. What makes it a code smell is that it could indicate a problematic source of coupling in your application. Sometimes removing that source of coupling is much more productive than writing a mock.

There are many kinds of coupling, and some are better than others. Understanding that mocks are a code smell can teach you to identify and avoid the worst kinds *early* in the application design lifecycle, *before* the smell develops into something worse.